# How to get city bound on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, wikimapia

I am currently using Wikimapia to get the object's polygon, which is also its bound. However, I cannot get the polygon of some large objects, such as cities or countries. I think that Wikimapia does not have such information.

Do you know any method to get that information from Google Maps or Wikimapia?

Best,
Cuong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible currently from Google Maps, sorry.

Answer (score 8):

Wikimapia has an API for this: http://wikimapia.org/api/

Google Maps can export data from MyMaps in KML files - but it only exports the data/polygons you create.

You might also be able to obtain this information from either http://www.openstreetmap.org/

or a Geographic Information System maintained by your local government.